# How to make style to extend but not override other styles

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

On the current window I have a Grid with multiple controls (labels, textboxes, buttons).
General styles are set in App.xaml. Extensions for each control are set in Grid resources.
Each control visibility is determined by viewmodel property value. Not to bind each controls visibility to it (it uses custom converter and this will cause lots duplications) I wish to have "MyVisible1" style.

The problem is if I apply this style it overlaps other properties. What value should I use in "BasedOn"? Or what else can I do to implement it?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="MyVisible1">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ...}" />
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="45" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MyVisible1}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I can imagine that you can do this is to define a local implicit `Style` for this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ...}" />
</Style>
```

By *not* defining an `x:Key`, this `Style` will be implicitly applied to all controls that extend the `Control` class and by declaring it locally, it will only apply to those elements in the current focus scope. So defining it in a `Grid.Resources` section will implicitly apply it to all controls within that `Grid`. You are then free to apply whatever additional `Style`s that you want to these controls.

Comment: I'll have multiple visibility styles. In this case your suggestion doesn't help. (

Comment: When I first started writing WPF, I always ended up with lots of duplicated code in various `Style`s, `ControlTemplate`s, `DataTemplate`s, etc. I spent ages trying to find ways to duplicate less code and found that it is often not possible. Then I came to realise that WPF is quite a verbose language compared with others and that it really doesn't matter if we duplicate a few bytes or even kilobytes of code.